# Calling a Javascript function via ssl

Tags: ssl, javascript, static-ip, iframe

Please excuse any ignorance on my part, I am very new to SSL and Javascript, so what I am asking may be obvious. I have tried to Google but can't seem to find the answer to my question.

Background

Basically, I have a website, with a subdomain that holds a rental car booking engine in an iframe, which is called from an external location using Javascript. We recently moved to SSL and now the booking engine does not display as it is deemed unsecure by web browsers.

I contacted the company that manages the booking engine and they advised that I needed an SSL for the subdomain, which they can load at their end as well (I bought a single domain, not a wildcard, my mistake), and I needed to purchase a static IP on their server. They sent me a quote for €130 per year for and a static IP.

My very limited knowledge of SSL seems to suggest that a static IP is not required, however I am probably wrong about this.

Question

Do I need the static IP for the SSL to work, or will the wildcard SSL resolve the issue?

I understand that the SSL for the subdomain is required, I just can't find an answer for the static IP.

Basically, I don't fully trust the company as they have tried to add unnecessary charges to invoices in the past.

Thanks in advance

edit: The setup is as follows

- www.example.com (our website, built on wordpress, has SSL, controlled by me)
- bookings.example.com (our subdomain, no file hosting but points at a specific IP address through DNS where the booking engine is hosted)(this does not yet have SSL)
- The booking engine we use is hosted on external servers and is managed by an external company.  We have no control over these servers

The booking engine is displayed on www.example.com using an iframe that calls the relevant information using javascript.

Comment: If you do not have a static ip, then you will have to continously update the DNS, for the sub-domain in question.  Since its unlikely you will have access to ssh or root on this server, and depending your knowlege in every other area requires to manage a server, you might be better off paying for the static ip address.

Comment: to clarify, our website is on a server with static IP, as is the subdomain calling the iframe.  The suggestion from them is that the booking engine does not have a static IP and they are saying it requires one...

Comment: So is this engine your using only accessible by your website or something?

Comment: So, its not clear to me how many servers are involved, what each server is doing, where SSL is already implemented and who controls what, and those details are necessary to answer this question.  Can you give an example setup and some more explaination using domains like `example.com` `subdomain.example.com` and the like?

Comment: I will also add that there was a time that you needed a unique IP address for each individual SSL certificate you were hosting, however with wildcard certificates and since [Subject Alternate Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) support is pretty much ubiquitous, having a unique IP is no longer a hard requirement but may require getting a new certificate.

Comment: I have edited the original question with the setup.  I currently have a single domain SSL but will purchase a wildcard to cover the subdomain etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you may have to just pay the money for the IP address and if it was me, I would purchase a second certificate just for `bookings.example.com`.

Just to be clear, my understanding is that `bookings.example.com` is pointing to an IP address that is managed by the booking engine company.

The reason I say that you're just going to have to pay for the IP is that in order for the booking company to serve multiple customer from a single IP using SSL, they would have to control the certificates so that they could list several clients on a single SSL cert via the Subject Alternate Name extension (companies like Cloudflare do this).  However since it sounds like you are responsible for acquiring the certificate, and therefore would be required to have your own IP.

I would recommend acquiring a unique certificate for `bookings.example.com` for security reasons.  You will be providing the booking engine company with your private key, and as soon as they have that key they could theoretically intercept your customer's traffic and decrypt it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

One more thing.  Could I have 3 separate certificates, 1 for the website, one for the subdomain, 1 for the booking engine server.  This would be the most secure, right?

Comment: So, a certificate is going to be assigned to a server, and from my understanding the subdomain's DNS A record contain booking engine server's IP, so I think having two would be redundant since they are the same server.  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

So, I would get a wildcard to cover my site and subdomain, and purchase a separate one for the booking engine?  I am concerned where you said that I would be giving my private key to the booking engine company, I want to avoid this

Comment: Yes a wildcard for your site (you keep that private key) and then a cert just for the subdomain, you would provide the booking company with this second private key so that their server can perform the encryption.  As long as you keep your original cert private key secret you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help! (although I now have to convince my boss to part with a couple hundred € per year...)

Comment: Don't try to convince your boss to part with the cost of the SSL certificates.  Instead, have your boss consider the cost of parting with the lost revenue from not being able to do business online.  That is the *real* cost involved here.

Comment: @twisty... it didn't take long...

Comment: @DavePenn You have a smart boss.